# When using MAX(column), values from other columns don't match

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the last "VERSION" for each NID with the corresponding REVID in the following table:

```
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+
| RHID | REVID | NID | VERSION |  ACTION  |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+ 
| 1    |   1   |  1  |    1    |  CREATE  |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+  
| 2    |   2   |  2  |    1    |  CREATE  |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+  
| 3    |   3   |  1  |    2    |  UPDATE  |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+  
| 4    |   4   |  1  |    3    |  UPDATE  |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+  
| 16   |   3   |  1  |    4    | ROLLBACK |
+------+-------+-----+---------+----------+
```

When I run:

```
SELECT a.nid, a.revID, MAX(a.version)
FROM `revision_history` a
GROUP BY a.nid;
```

I expect the result to be:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| NID | REVID | VERSION |
+-----+-------+---------+
|  1  |   3   |    4    |
+-----+-------+---------+
|  2  |   2   |    1    |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

Instead the results are:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| NID | REVID | VERSION |
+-----+-------+---------+
|  1  |   3   |    4    |
+-----+-------+---------+
|  2  |   2   |    4    |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

---

**Q. What is the appropriate query to obtain the results I expect?**

NOTE:

This is to build a view (which, in MySQL, does not support subqueries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select a.nid ,a.revID ,a.version
from   `revision_history` a
JOIN
      (SELECT nid,  MAX(version) as version
        FROM `revision_history` 
        GROUP BY nid)b
ON    a.nid=b.nid
AND   a.version=b.version
```

#### [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f920b/3)

Comment: Not sure this will work as is for a view. However think you could have your subquery as a view, and join that view with the table to make up a 2nd view.

Comment: Thanks. And If I want to build a view from the results I have to create a helper view with the subquery select statement right?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: Thanks.. I was making a fiddle .. you made my job easier :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: I learned it recently.. very useful feature :)) anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to asume that `GROUP BY` takes the first value in `FROM`:

```
SELECT nid ,revID ,version
FROM (  SELECT nid, revID, version
        FROM `revision_history`
        ORDER BY version DESC) AS h
GROUP BY nid
```

The method is quite short, easy to understand and edit if you know the behavior and never gets more than 1 case. If you for some reason would have 2 identical version on the same `nid`, result might be wrong.